# Laravel Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach/attach() for hasManyThrough relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

There are two important models `Resume` and `Skill`. `Resume` has many skills through `ResumeSkill`.

When I submit my form with skills, before adding them to resume, I remove all the skills it already has.

But I'm having this problem when I run the methods `attach()` and `detach()`:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::detach()

This is my Resume model class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Resume extends BaseModel{
    public function skills(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\myApp\Skill', '\myApp\ResumeSkill');
    }
}
```

And the main script:

```
$record = \myApp\Resume::find($id);
$record->skills()->detach();
foreach($skills as $skill_id){
   $record->skills()->attach($skill_id);
}
```

What is wrong? Some answers I see say `attach()` is a BelongsTo method, but they must be old answers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through. Anyway, associate/dissociate don't work as well.

**@solved**

I should have used `BelongsToMany`. And `attach` / `detach` **DOES** work with this relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hasManyThrough is a short-cut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For Many-to-many relations is define method belongsToMany.

```
public function skills() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill', 'ResumeSkill', 'idResume', 'idSkill');
}
```

Comment: but there is an intermediate table. what is a distant relation?

Comment: In the case we have three tables, such as countries, users and comments and I want to get all the comments of a particular country. In the Country model would use this implementation: public function comments() { return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Comment', 'App\User'); }